# Batch file execution issue with goto's

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a script that shuts tomcat off, runs a cleanup file, then starts the service again. I'm looping through waiting for a Specific line in my log file, for me its "INFO: Server Startup in". I then want to go to the running section prompting me that the service is back up and running. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

- The service stop is working
- The Pending section is working
- The Stopped section is working
- The loop section is not working properly im not seeing any echos
- The Running section is not working, im not seeing ant of the echo
  statements

Here is what I have written so far. I am new to batch scripting so please forgive me for syntax issues.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "Tomcat7" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
 if /I "%%H" equ "RUNNING" (
    echo Service Tomcat7 is "%%H" Stopping Service now
    net stop "Tomcat7"
    goto :pending
 )
)

:pending
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "Tomcat7" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
 if /I "%%H" equ "STOP_PENDING" (
    echo Service Tomcat7 is running Stopping Service is "%%H"
    timeout /t 15
    goto :pending
 )
 else(
    goto :stopped
 )
)

:stopped
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "Tomcat7" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
 if /I "%%H" equ "STOPPED" (
    echo Service Tomcat7 has "%%H"
    echo Cleaning up the log files
    cleanup.bat
    echo ################# Starting Service Tomcat7 #################
    net Start "Tomcat7"
    timeout /t 15 /nobreak > NUL
    goto :loop
 )
)

:loop
findstr /m "INFO: Server startup in" C:\Apps\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\logs\tomcat7-stderr*
if %errorlevel%==0 (
  echo Found Server Startup!
  goto :running
) else (
echo Server is loading files Please wait...
  timeout /t 15
  goto :loop
)

:running
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "Tomcat7" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
 if /I "%%H" equ "RUNNING" (
    echo Service Tomcat7 is "%%H"
    timeout /t 30
 )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
call cleanup.bat
```

If you do not include the `call`, execution is transfered to the called batch file and does not return to the caller batch file.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it! Ill post a cleaned up answer.

Answer (score 0):

Working fix was just missing the call command! Cleaned it up a bit.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "Tomcat7" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
 if /I "%%H" equ "RUNNING" (
    echo Service Tomcat7 is "%%H" Stopping Service now
    net stop "Tomcat7"
    goto pending
 )
)

:pending
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "Tomcat7" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
 if /I "%%H" equ "STOP_PENDING" (
    echo Service Tomcat7 is running Stopping Service is "%%H"
    timeout /t 15 
    goto pending
 )
 else(
    goto stopped
 )
)

:stopped
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "Tomcat7" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
 if /I "%%H" equ "STOPPED" (
    echo Service Tomcat7 has "%%H"
    echo Cleaning up the log files
    call cleanup.bat
    echo ################# Starting Service Tomcat7 #################
    net Start "Tomcat7"
    timeout /t 10 /nobreak > NUL
    echo loading server config
    goto loading
 )
)

:loading
findstr /m /c:"INFO: Server startup in" C:\Apps\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\logs\tomcat7-stderr*
  if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo Found Server Startup!
    goto running
  ) else (
    echo No matches found
    timeout /t 15
    goto loading
  )

:running
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "Tomcat7" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" equ "RUNNING" (
    echo Service Tomcat7 is "%%H"
    goto fin
  ) else (
    timeout /t 15
    goto running
  )
)

:fin
echo ############### FINISHED ###############
timeout /t 45
```